# Is it good practice to send page name through sessions in php 7.1?

Tags: php, html, session, title

***Hello,*** I started learning PHP, I set myself a goal to make a website,
which would be similar to social network, as I am newbie, I don't know what is good or bad, I can code simple functions, have fundamentals of HTML, CSS, JS. But I want to learn more deeply, like what practices should I use and which I shouldn't

---

Here is the code of **header.php** :

```
<?php
    $page = $_SESSION['page'];
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><?php echo $page ?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>HEADER</h3>
        </body>
    </html>
    <hr>
```

And here is the code of **index.php** :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['page'] = "Pradinis Puslapis";
    require('tpl/header.php');
    echo "Hello World!";
    ?>
<hr>
```

Of course, I would include footer too, and also in **index.php** I would implement html code specially designed for that page, but like I wrote, I want to know If I am thinking good - to send page's name through 
**$_SESSION** variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a session in your case. When you include your header you can use your variables directly in your included script. When you have a template engine you take another way. In that case you load a template file and replace your variables and return the parsed HTML code to your PHP file and print them out.

**main.php**

```
$page = "Test";
require('tpl/header.php');
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $page ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>HEADER</h3>
</body>
</html>
<hr>
```

What you try here is good for learning but not really common in production. There are a ton of really good Frameworks that gives you a perfect structure and help you to prevent mistakes. For your Programm you could start with a template engine like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) or [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) for example. So first you should learn the basics then you can build a website on your own or good tools. Building a good framework is really hard.

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted... Frameworks are good. I tried laravel. But still. I thought It would be better If I would learn to do it by myself, and then I could move to development with frameworks. Thank  you for answer!

Comment: @LukasPabijonavičius yes ok but the problem is that this what you try is not a really good way to build a good site. All that frameworks use a lot good techniques. And Laravel for example that use that structure. So perhaps you should look how they do it and try to understand it.